# Behavior of TransferManager on network issue

Tags: android, web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

While uploading using TransferManager, if a network issue occurs, it would be caught in the exception - AmazonClientException. In such cases do I have to abort the current upload? If I want to upload the file again do I have to begin a new upload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted on your other question, the S3 TransferManager does not currently support resuming of uploads.  We'll consider adding this in future versions on the SDK.

Comment: In case if the upload is interrupted do i have to call abort. Will the space used by the upload be automatically removed in case if the upload is not able to complete.

Comment: How can i abort the particular upload using TransferManager. By using the Abort in highlevel api is it possible only to abort the uploads to a bucket before particular date. How can i specify to abort a particular upload.

Comment: @ElezabethMathew Yes, space used for partial uploads will count against your usage for S3.  You can read more about abort options for the TransferManager [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLAbortMPUJava.html) and [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLAbortMPUploadsJava.html)

Comment: Is there a way to abort uploads to a particular folder in a bucket.

Comment: @ElezabethMathew You could list the multipart uploads with the prefix of the folder and get all ids for a particular "folder" in a bucket, then abort those.

Comment: thanks a lot for the above tip. Does the TransferManager handles timeout error as the AmazonS3.putObject() does. Can i configure how many retries the client uses by instantiating it with a ClientConfiguration object.